# Use function of a controller in another angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, controllers

Few days I've been trying to solve it using a function of a controller in another.

I have to get is that when you press a button click go away to another part of the application but with an open form. I have a function that opens the form in your controller working perfectly but I need to invoke that function from another part of the application for this (or it might please him happens to someone other way).

I hope you can help me I do not know what else to give ...

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: i think you used the service that used anywhere in program .

Answer (score 2):

Move the function inside a factory. You can inject this factory in any controller to access the function.

```
controller('controller1', function(sharedFunctions){
   sharedFunctions.function1();
})

controller('controller2', function(sharedFunctions){
   sharedFunctions.function1();
})

factory('sharedFunctions', function(){

   return {
      function1: function() {
         console.log('function1 called')' 
      }    
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad answer: you can do this if the scope of your controller is child of the other controller (the one with the function to call). I believe this is not your case.

Better answer: you should move this function to a service, so that you can reuse it and call it from anyother place of your application. If the function is well written (loose coupled) it should be easy to do this.